# Need help with configurable product

Tags: configurable-product

I have created a configurable product in my store following the Magento official tutorial.
After creating the product, on the website, on the product page the following info appears:

[image]

What can I do to make disappear the "+65,50 RON" value next to the quantity of the product?
The Ambalaj attribute is referring to quantity and RON is the currency in my country.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can price remove in dropdown this way.. 
Override below file in your theme then change it

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

to

> app/design/frontend/PACKAGE_NAME/THEME_NAME/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

```
allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);

if (typeof allowedProducts[0] !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof optionPrices[allowedProducts[0]] !== 'undefined') {
    allowedProductMinPrice = this._getAllowedProductWithMinPrice(allowedProducts);
    optionFinalPrice = parseFloat(optionPrices[allowedProductMinPrice].finalPrice.amount);
    optionPriceDiff = optionFinalPrice - basePrice;

    /*if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
        options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
            optionPriceDiff,
            this.options.priceFormat,
            true);
    }*/
}
```

and comment this condition  `if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {` like above code then again run

```
rm -rf var/di/* generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f


php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you so much!